# "would you like______cup of blood?"count duclia said to lord voldmart

Tags: sentence-construction

> Q: "Would you like ______ cup of blood?" Count Duclia said to Lord Voldmart.

options given:

a. drinking
 b. having
 c. another
 d. tasting

My Approach:

Drinking, another both can be true according to me.

Is there any other way through which I can analyze the problem to choose appropriate answer or is the Answer correct?

Comment: In English, those names are spelled `Count Dracula` and `Lord Voldemort`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this quotation, the only possible answer is C - "another".

The reason for this is that all of the other options require an article before "cup".

> A - Would you like drinking **a** cup of blood?
>
> B - Would you like having **a** cup of blood?
>
> D - Would you like tasting **a** cup of blood?

All of the other options require the article, so the only correct option is "another".

> C - Would you like another cup of blood?

As a note, because it came up in the comments, adding "a" to options A, B, and D do not make them *mean* the same thing as sentence C. They become grammatical by adding "a" but the meaning is quite different.

Sentence C is offering the listener a second cup of blood - "another" implies that they've already consumed at least one cup of blood.

The other three sentences are asking a theoretical question along the lines of

> Do you think you would like to [enjoy the action of] drink/have/taste a cup of blood?

This phrasing assumes that the speaker believes the listener has never drunk/had/tasted blood in the past.

---

Why "a" instead of "the":

"The" is certainly possible but I'd argue that it's less common. Generally, if someone offers you a glass of wine (or blood), they don't offer you "the" (only) glass of wine, they offer you "a" (one of many) glass of wine.

Without some context, it's difficult to know whether there is only a single cup/glass or if there are several and you're being offered a single one.

Let's look at the sentences with "the" and what they mean:

> Would you like drinking the cup of blood?

This is certainly possible but, as I mentioned above, it implies that there is only one cup. This also has a speculative quality to it, as if you're asking not, "do you want to drink it" but, "how would you feel about drinking it"?

Personally, as a native speaker, should this be the case, I would prefer the construction:

> Would you like to drink the cup of blood?

The same issues occur with the other two examples.

My preferred "the" phrasings of the other two would be:

> Would you like to have the cup of blood?

This implies more of a sense of ownership of the cup rather than consuming the blood it contains.

> Would you like to taste the cup of blood?

This sounds a bit odd because it sounds more like you're asking if they would like to taste the cup, which happens to be full of blood... which is silly, since you can't eat or drink a (presumably) inedible vessel. So, my truly preferred version of this would be:

> Would you like to taste the blood in this cup?

Regardless, the only answer above that works is still "another".

Comment: having a cup or the cup?Similarly for tasting,having too

Comment: @JalajChawla "The" is certainly possible but I'd argue that it's less common. Generally, if someone offers you a glass of wine, they don't offer you "the" (only) glass of wine, they offer you "a" (one of many) glass of wine. If there is **only** a single glass, and they're offering you a taste of it, they would be more likely (in my opinion) to say "Would you like to taste some of this wine"?

Comment: `Would you like drinking a cup of blood` and its sister sentences sound completely wrong to me. `Like`, when associated with a verb, is almost always formed with the infinitive `to drink`. The only exception I can think of is the past tense, `Did you like running the marathon?` in which case, `running` is a gerund (a noun), not a verb anyway.

Comment: Suggesting that merely supplying an article prior to *cup* is sufficient in the other three instances is such a bad recommendation that I must downvote. *Would you like drinking/having/tasting* is an awful construction. You do suggest the correct construction (*Would you like to drink/have/taste*) later on, but mark it merely as your preference – this is not a matter of preference. As @PressTilty indicates, in the past tense (*Did you like drinking/having/tasting*), the *-ing* form is acceptable, but not with *would* as you have it. That construction is *wrong*.

Comment: @KRyan not really. "Would you like having a baby brother?" It's not a **great** construction but it's not ungrammatical.

Comment: @KRyan and I completely disagree with you. If you want to cite a source showing it's wrong, or write an answer explaining it, I encourage that but there is nothing I see about the phrase that sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Catija (previous comment deleted because it was posted incomplete by mistake) It is wrong because no English speaker would say it that way, and that is all the reason English needs. English is not a language of rules. The brother example is fine because an English speaker would say it that way. Why one is acceptable and the other not is beyond the scope of comments, but ultimately it is so. You yourself note that you wouldn't say it that way or expect others to -- so why would you suggest that it is OK to a learner?

Comment: @KRyan I think you may be inferring something into the sentence that isn't there... If I was asking someone "What do you think, would you like drinking a cup of blood?".. there's nothing wrong with that sentence and I, as a native speaker, would use it. That question is asking: *do you think you would like the action of "drinking a cup of blood"*... And that's a perfectly reasonable thing to ask someone.

Comment: @Catija Then we agree to disagree. I would call your example wrong.

Comment: @Catija Now that you've clarified, I understand what your sentences are trying to say. However, `Would you like to drink a cup of blood?` and `Would you like drinking a cup of blood?` are semantically different. I believe your answer is misleading, and suggests they are synonymous. It took me, a native speaker, multiple re-reads to parse it, and I think you should clarify for the learners.

Comment: @KRyan, she's trying to say something along the lines of `In your opinion, would you like drinking a cup of blood, since its texture and flavor is probably repulsive` in the same manner as `Would you like having a brother in your day to day life`, as opposed to the more general `Are you agreeable to the idea of a younger sibling?`. Regardless, it is an awkward construction, and unhelpful for learners.

Comment: @PressTilty Yes, they mean different things but, realistically, I never say that they mean anything. I don't even talk about what they mean at all... because that's not what the question is asking for, so I didn't feel it was necessary. There's no context in the question to know what's actually being meant by the example, so it's completely possible that either meaning is valid.

Comment: @Catija. Edited. But taken in context with the correct answer `another`, I think it's clear the question is looking for a sentence with the value `would you like me to serve you another cup of blood, so you can drink it?`. It seems highly unlikely an English test as basic as this is truly looking for nuance as subtle as `how would you like the action of drinking this particular liquid?`

Comment: @PressTilty Ah, I see. Yes, if that is the intent, then this answer is remarkably unclear, and I find it even more deserving of a downvote. In context, that meaning is very unlikely (both characters drink blood), and if nothing else, the way this affects the meaning needs to be in the answer if that unlikely construction is to be considered at all.

Comment: @KRyan There's no context in the original sentence that implies that the alternate meaning is wrong... nothing about the context implies that "Lord Voldmart" has ever consumed blood in the past, so, as I've said already, the definition of the sentences is irrelevant. But, because you seem so intent on it, I have clarified in my answer.

Comment: @Catija Not wrong, per se. Just much less likely.

Comment: @PressTilty Yes... particularly as the word "a" is missing.

Comment: @Catija Yes, haha. I believe your edits addressed the issue.

Comment: Personally, although I "get" `would you like drinking a cup of blood`, etc. I don't think I would ever use them and would assume they were deliberate, effected, or perhaps written by a non-native speaker. It's easy to say that and maybe there have been times when I've said something like `would you like drinking...` - but I'm confident I would almost always go with `would you enjoy drinking...` or `would you feel happy/comfortable/good (about) drinking ...`, but it just doesn't work for me with 'like'.

Comment: Maybe because I'm so used to `would you like...` meaning `do you want...` `I  like having a cup of blood` wouldn't work for me, *but*, in fairness, `I like having stuff to do` is very natural to me. `Would you like having stuff to do`, however, isn't. So maybe it's at least partially related to `would you like` being parsed as `do you want`. Whatever the reason, I think you're first three sentences sound really forced. Maybe it's a geographical difference?